# Cannot unpickle arrays and a matplotlib figure

Tags: python-3.x, import, io, pickle, keyerror

This is one of my first times using `pickle`. I am conducting some Monte Carlo simulations in Python and I have stored some parameters, some numpy arrays and a matplotlib figure in the `results.pickle` file using the following code:

```
sim_results = {'n_replications': n_replications, 'p': 0, 'alpha_0': alpha_0, 'sample_size': n_sample, 'decay': decay,
          'cy': cy, 'cd': cd, 'penalty_list':penalty_list, 'single_estimates': single_estimates, 
           'double_estimates': double_estimates, 'plot': f}

pickle_out = open('results.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(sim_results, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

After that, I am trying to load them into another Python 3.6 session using

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

pickle_in = open("results.pickle", 'rb')
simulation = pickle.load(pickle_in)
pickle_in.close()
```

However, I have this KeyError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Raul/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 1684, in __setstate__
    self._init(state['child'])
KeyError: 'child'
```

I have browsed around but I have no idea of what is going on. Can you guys help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I ran into this same error message after installing pyinstaller and pywin32. Prior to this I was able to open and read pickle files.